If I have a png image of a clut(Color Look Up Table), how do I convert it to a 5x4 filter matrix？
Color Look Up Table
I have no idea.I'm not familiar with Color Look Up Table. Has anyone dealt with this kind of problem.I want to convert the color mapping table into a matrix for image processing. Can someone help me? Thank you
